# Did the Christians plagiarize the holy war concept?

Tags: christianity, islam, crusades

In my other question:

[Christian and Etruscan end of times](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/14109/christian-and-etruscan-end-of-times?noredirect=1#comment36054_14109)

I've asked why the Romans, the Byzantines and the Etruscans, in times of trouble, devoted themselves to contemplating the afterlife and did not respond with something akin to a holy war (i.e. something electrifying that would bring huge numbers of recruits into the ranks). The answer may be that no one invented the holy war until Islam came about. So, are the Muslims the originators of the holy war concept, which the Christian world then copied?

Comment: The Christian crusade concept was a pilgrimage-one where you bring all your weapons. It's not a jihad idea.

Comment: So in other words, its possible to have similarities in outcome from differing ideas. This would be one example.

Comment: @RazieMah So the Muslims were the first who made use of this recruiting tool, you agree? In any case you did not answer my question.

Comment: I think you need to define "Holy War." I think your definition might be very vague and then it would be a cross-cultural concept. I'm pretty sure it becomes unanswerable though at that point though, since cultures without writing systems used religious ritual as part of warfare.

Comment: @RazieMah My question referred specifically to "outcomes", i.e. if you need recruits, a "holy war" (whatever that means) might be a solution. Of course, Muslims and Christians would have different perceptions of what a "holy war" might be. I asked, if the Muslims were the first users of this recruitment tool. I also think, you don't pull in recruits by rationally defining "holy war" to them, but play on their emotions. An exact definition may therefore not even exist.

Comment: Ok, if I'm understanding then, you want to know who used religion first as a recruitment tool?

Comment: @RazieMah Yes, as apparently both the Latin and Byzantine Christians failed to make any use of it, as well as everyone else before them, as far as I know.

Comment: sounds like just an anti-Christian rant, not a serious question.

Comment: The first real Catholic "crusade" (the word didn't exist yet) was Charlemagne's holy war against the Saxons from 772- 804 AD. I see no reason why Charles needed to borrow the idea from the Muslims, this wasn't the first time religion was involved in war.

Comment: @JeroenK What makes you think that was a Crusade? It always seemed a plain old war of conquest to me. The pope did not call for it.

Comment: From [wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxon_Wars) "The chief purpose of the diet was to bring Saxony closer to Christianity. Missionaries, mainly Anglo-Saxons from England, were recruited to carry out this task. Charlemagne issued a number of decrees designed to break Saxon resistance and to inflict capital punishment on anyone observing heathen practices or disrespecting the king's peace. (...) as God's word should be spread not by the sword but by persuasion; but the wars continued."

Comment: @JeroenK And the fact he enlarged his tax base and territory played no part at all? If some piece of religious propaganda from the times survived, I'd believe it was a Crusade in an instant.

Comment: As you know those arguments can be made for the crusading knights as well, many of them took land and titles in Palestine or Syria. Written propaganda did not exist in a time when only the clergy could read (even Charlemagne was illiterate) but yes as you could have read in the quote or the article texts do survive, the most well known being the [Capiltulatio de partibus Saxoniae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitulatio_de_partibus_Saxoniae). As you can read in the article it specifies that Saxons unwilling to convert would be brought to death (the German article version is more complete).

Comment: @JeroenK As you know, the Quran "survived" (along with its propaganda) in oral form until it was written down. I just don't have a feeling of a Levee en masse with Charlemagne's effort. Further, the payment for partaking in a Crusade was, at least, formally, in the spiritual domain (the remittance of sins, ...) and a king could not grant that (AFAIK).

Comment: Voting down as this smells like a rant. I can't see any clear question being asked here.

Answer (score 5):

Religion has been used by all groups of peoples to help them understand and regulate warfare and thus also to convince people to take part (recruit them). Provided [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_war_deities) is a Wikipedia list of war gods. In a monotheistic religion, the role of the war god is combined as a trait of the one god. In the Old Testament, the Jewish God can be seen commanding his people to go to war to defeat peoples who commit grave sins. In other religions, the people might take captives to use as human sacrifice, such as the pre Buddhist deity Dayisum Tngri. Burial of slaves, often war captives, at a master's death was a common form of human sacrifice in other cultures.

The Nuristani people are a very old culture. They are mentioned in the Rigveda, one of the world's oldest manuscripts, composed in 1500-1200BCE. Their war god is Great Gish. After an enemy is killed in battle, a victory dance is given to Great Gish. This type of religious ritual would have been common among tribes without writing systems, as well, so it is impossible to know which peoples did this first.

Comment: Sure, sure, but many ideas were carried over from the Muslims. Lost books from antiquity survived in Muslim hands, knowledge about siege warfare, ... The Muslims, also, learned many things from elsewhere and they figured out others themselves. I was asking whether the "holy war" idea was borrowed/copied over from the Muslim world into the Christian world. It could be, that the Muslims only transmitted it.

Comment: @user1095108 That contradicts the Hadith, so I don't think so. Also, there were episodes of large forced conversions in Europe before the Crusades, so they didn't need to transmit the idea.

Comment: I don't think seeking converts was a prime concern on the mind of the Crusaders, nor of the Mujaheddin either. If it was, there would not be as many atrocities, as there were. About the Hadith... quote?

Comment: @user1095108 I said "in Europe before the Crusades." You will need to read the Hadith. My point is that Muhammed was inspired by visions to set rules for Jihad involving warfare, but this was before the Arabs conquered major empires.

Comment: He set the rules and they worked. Soon the Arab peninsula, Egypt and the Levant were conquered. This only proved the utility of a "holy war" and might have motivated imitators, similar to how effective weapons are often copied from captured examples.

Comment: @user1095108 That's good thinking honestly, but there are religious differences. Remember that Holy War is first about religion, not really politics. The Muslims fight and convert people because they are submitting to Allah's will that all people should be Muslim. It saves their soul to do this. The Christians convert people to save the converts souls, so while it was common among Christians, they never fully adopted a jihad. Conversion by force doesn't work in Christianity, since the person must accept Christ themselves or they aren't saved. Maybe other cultures adopted it though? Not sure.

Comment: @user1095108 Holy War (or however you want to call warfare using religion as an excuse) has been part and parcel of propaganda for as long as religions exist. Mohammed didn't invent it, he just used what he knew was something that works to stir up the masses.

Comment: @jwenting And Urban II learned the trick from Mohammed and adapted it to his own needs?